# Fill form multiple time before submit and insert counter

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have created a form and a button in this form (add +) which allows me to insert the form multiple times before the final validation . For this I have created a list which receives the different insertions and a counter which allows me to know the number of insertions . but the problem is that when I click on (add +) the counter doesn't increment and I receive this error  :

```
core.js:6141 ERROR TypeError: ctx_r28.addaction is not a function
at AdvanceTableComponent_ng_template_46_Template_button_click_103_listener (advance-table.component.html:223)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15192)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15227)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:402)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28499)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:401)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:174)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:483)
at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1596)
```

and I can't insert data in my list.

**my code**

```
 <ng-template #editRecord let-modal>
              <div class="modal-header editRowModal">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">
                  <div class="table-modal-header">
                    <div class="modal-about">
                      <div class="font-weight-bold p-t-10 font-17">
                      Création des actions</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                  <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="material-icons">close</i></span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onEditSave(editForm)">
                  
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label>Domaine <span class="text-succes">*</span></label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domaine" formControlName="domaine" readonly=""
                        required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label> Id probleme<span class="text-succes" >*</span></label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="id" formControlName="idprblm" readonly=""  >
                     
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label >Personne(s) à notifier <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <select class="form-control"  required>
                        <option value="2" selected disabled>Ahmed</option>
                        <option value="3" selected disabled>Hasssan</option>
                        <option value="1" selected >Choisissez les personn</option>
                      </select>                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label> Cause du probleme<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" formControlName="causeprblm" placeholder="Mentionner la cause source du probleme" ></textarea>
                     
                    </div>
                     
                  </div>
               
                  
                  
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label>Action<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" formControlName="action" placeholder="Mentionner l'action éliminant la cause"
                        ></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                       
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label>Responsable Action<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="respaction" placeholder="Mentionner le porteur de l'action"  required>
                 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label>Date de réalisation <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <input type="datetime" class="form-control" formControlName="daterealisation" placeholder="Mentionner la date de réalisation objective"  required>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label>Statut <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <select class="form-control" formControlName="statut" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Plan</option>
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Do</option>
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Check</option>
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Act</option>
                        <option value="" selected >Statut</option>
                        
                      </select> 
                    </div>
                 
                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold p-t-10 font-17">Méthodologie :</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">

                      <div class="form-check">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="methodologie" id="customCheck2">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">8D</label>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold p-t-10 font-17" style="color: orange;">Escalade :</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">

                      <div class="form-check">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck4">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck4"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 24px; color: orange;"></i>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                       
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold p-t-10 font-17" style="color: orange;"></label>

                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <button  class="icon-button1" (click)="addaction()" style="background-color: #E8F7F4">
                          <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px; color:#88D279


                          ;" type="success">add_circle
                          </span>
                          <span class="icon-button__badge1" style="background-color:#C5E8BA
                          ">{{countaction}}</span>
                        </button> 


                      </div>
                    </div>


                  </div>
                 
                
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!editForm.valid">Créer</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="modal.close()">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
```

**TS file**

```
  countaction :number = 0;
  actionlist: Array<object> = [];
  editForm: FormGroup;
   constructor( private fb: FormBuilder,){

 this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      domaine:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      idprblm:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      persnotif: [''],
      causeprblm:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      action:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      respaction:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      daterealisation:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      statut:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      methodologie:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      excalade:  ['', [Validators.required]],
    });}
//add action 
  onAddAction(form:FormGroup) {
    this.actionlist.push(form.value);
    this.countaction = ++this.countaction;
  console.log(this.actionlist)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is simple fix for this problem, I have checked the HTML code and I found "addaction" which I believe is used to increment the count. But I didn't find any function with same name in the component, so you can add the function name in the ts file.

```
public addaction() {
   this.countaction = ++this.countaction;
   console.log(this.countaction); 
}
```

Or,

```
public onAddAction() { // remove the parameter
    this.actionlist.push(this.editForm.value); // this will give you the form values
    this.countaction = ++this.countaction;
  console.log(this.actionlist)
  }

//in Html code

<button  class="icon-button1" (click)="onAddAction()" style="background-color: #E8F7F4"> // change the function name

   <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px; color:#88D279;" type="success">add_circle</span>

    <span class="icon-button__badge1" style="background-color:#C5E8BA">{{countaction}}</span>

</button>
```

Comment: This worked for me but when I fill the form and click in add , it doesn't empty the fields

Comment: You should add that code to empty the newly added field, specify the value="" when you create it or may be you can assign any other value.